# Como exportar .csv com Django-Tables2?

Tags: python-3.x, django

Estou tentando exportar uma tabela com Django-Tables2, fiz o seguinte até agora.

**tables.py**

```py
class ClienteTable(ColumnShiftTable):

    class Meta:
        model = Cliente
        sequence = ('id', 'nome_razao_social', 'cpf', 'cnpj', 'sit_fiscal')
        template_name = 'django_tables2/bootstrap.html'
```

**views.py**

```py
class RelatorioClientesView(ExportMixin, CustomListView):
    template_name = 'relatorios/clientes/geral.html'
    model = Cliente
    table_class = ClienteTable
    context_object_name = 'all_clientes'
    permission_codename = 'view_clientes'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(RelatorioClientesView,
                        self).get_context_data(**kwargs)

        table = ClienteTable(Cliente.objects.all())
        table.paginate(page=self.request.GET.get('page', 1), per_page=15)

        context['table'] = table
        RequestConfig(self.request).configure(table) #ordena

        export_format = self.request.GET.get('_export', None)
        if TableExport.is_valid_format(export_format):
            exporter = TableExport(export_format, table)
            return exporter.response('table.{}'.format(export_format))

        return context
```

**template.html**

```html
<div class="tabela" style="overflow-x: auto; white-space: nowrap;">
    {% load render_table from django_tables2 %}
    {% render_table table %}

    {% export_url "csv" %}
</div>
```

Mas recebo esse erro `Invalid block tag on line 56: 'export_url', expected 'endblock'. Did you forget to register or load this tag?`

O que estou fazendo errado?

Comment: vc ta seguindo esse [tutorial](https://django-tables2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pages/export.html?highlight=export_url)?

Comment: Sim, estou seguindo